# How to deal with times per distance data in R

Tags: r, lubridate

I have data where I have times e.g. 11:42.7 (format "%M:%OS") that were needed to travel a certain distance (e.g. 3000 m). Now, I want to be able to calculate split times (e.g. time needed per 500 m).

```
timeVar  <- "11:42.7"
distance <- 3000
```

I tried this to calculate it:

```
(strptime(timeVar, "%M.%S")/distance)*500
```

but this returns: Error in Ops.POSIXt(strptime(timeVar, "%M.%S"), distance) : 
  '/' not defined for "POSIXt" objects.

With the package lubridate I can calculate this:

```
library(lubridate)
(as.duration(ms(timeVar))/distance)*500
```

which returns [1] "117.116666666667s (~1.95 minutes)" but I want the result to be in the format ("%M:%OS"). Is there a need way of handling this? For instance, I want to plot the data where I use the format on one of the axis but I also want to use the data for regression analysis. Similar things are possible with the POSIXt format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `seconds_to_period` (in **lubridate**) to get it into minutes/seconds. Then, use `sprintf` to format it as you like, as follows:

```
time <- seconds_to_period((as.duration(ms(timeVar))/distance)*500)

sprintf('%02d:%2.1f', minute(time), second(time)) # 01:57.1
#or using paste0
paste0(minute(time),':',round(second(time),1))  # 1:57.1
#or if you want it with hours
paste0(time@hour,':',minute(time),':',round(second(time),1)) # 0:1:57.1
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

If you convert to `period`, you can use `sprintf`:

```
library(lubridate)

d <- as.period(as.duration(ms(timeVar))/distance*500)
sprintf('%02d:%2.1f', minute(d), ms(d))
# "01:57.1"
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution using the hms package:

```
library(hms)
timeVar1 <- strptime(timeVar, "%M:%OS")
timeVar1 <- as.hms(timeVar1)

split500 <- (timeVar1/distance)*500
# Time difference of 117.1167 secs

split500 <- as.hms(split500)
# 00:01:57.116667
```